# Flex layout : Changes made to a single state

Tags: apache-flex, layout, states

I was modifying the layout of a Flex application in Flex Builder. What I didn't realize was that the changes I made, were made for a particular state. There are around 6-7 states in my application. Now, I need those changes to be made to all of those states. How do I do it? As of now there are multiple lines like this in one state :

```
        <mx:SetProperty target="{accno}" name="x" value="116"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{accno}" name="y" value="826"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{phone}" name="x" value="116"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{phone}" name="y" value="866"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the positions are relative, you can use math in your bindings.  Why don't you bind x & y on accno and phone to variables, and do math for the relative position?

```
<?phonetag? x='{accno_x}' y='{accno_y + 40}' .../>
```

Would that work?  Then you just need an accno_x and accno_y variable on your page.  You can also just make phone's x & y relative to accno:

```
<?phonetag? x='{accno.x}' y='{accno.y + 40}' .../>
```

Comment: accno and phone are just two of the list, there are around 27 such items

Comment: That's fine, are the positions relative?  If so, use math to determine the relative values.